# How to scroll bar for list view separator in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, scrollbar

I want to use `ScrollBar` widget to show a scrollbar for my `ListView.separated`. I have no error, but the ScrollBar is not shown. How can I fix this?

My code:

```dart
Scrollbar(
  thumbVisibility: true,
  trackVisibility: true,
  thickness: 10,
  controller: controller.firstController,
  child: ListView.separated(
    controller: controller.firstController,
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: EnergyList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        leading: Text(
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          '${index + 1}-',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, height: 1.5),
        ),
        title: Text(
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          EnergyList[index].sentences,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, height: 1.1),
        ),
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return const Divider(
        thickness: 3,
        height: 3,
        color: Colors.black,
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! When writing questions, be sure to indent the code correctly, to make it more readable and have a better chance of getting an answer. To avoid doing it manually, you can copy and paste the code like normal text in the question, then select the code and click the format code button.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in both (just replacing EnergyList[index].sentences with "Hello World") iOS and Chrome, and Scrollbar is showing always:

[image]

[image]

Comment: but I have not the scroll bar yet. can this problem because of the simulator? if  yes I think I should try it in real phone or another simulator as soon as possible.